# gazebo ros plugin getValueDouble deprecated

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I am converting a model plugin written for old version to gazebo (1.2 I believe) for gazebo 2.1. I have converted the includes in my header, the new are:

```
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <sdf/Param.hh>
#include <sdf/sdf.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>

//ros includes
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Quaternion.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
```

However, I am getting the following warning:

> warning: ‘double
> sdf::Element::GetValueDouble(const
> string&)’ is deprecated (declared at
> /usr/include/sdformat-1.4/sdf/SDFImpl.hh:220)
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

indicating the method deprecated. I checked and is deprecated since version 1.6. I tried to see what is the equivalent for the new version, but I cannot find it. The problem is that for the newest version is not documented (not even 2.0) and the wiki is poor (to be gentle). I tried to look in the api in v. 1.9.1 is said to be deprecated but no alternative is provided. In v. 2.0, instead, the sdf class does not exist at all (of course).
Can anyone help me please?

P.s. Someone should really improve the documentation

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5070/gazebo-ros-plugin-getvaluedouble-deprecated/) by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-11-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-11-26**:
+1, I am also wondering until when we can use the deprecated versions, and with what should we change them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

All of the `GetX` have been replaced with `Get<type>`.

For example: `Get<std::string>("name_of_sdf_element")`.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) on 2013-11-28**:
Thanks alot, may I ask you why it is not written anywhere?